# Matrix : get positive value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [Curtain JS](http://www.the.gs/fresh/curtain/example/) plugin for my website and I need to have the position of my first panel. For that I need to get the value of the CSS property `transform: translateY`.

For that I get the matrix which returns me something like that : [1,0,-1000,0].

So I use this JS code to get it :

```
 var matrix = $('.curtain-wrapper').css('transform');
 var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
 var x = values[5];
```

This code work fine. But it returns me a negative value : -1000, -900 etc...

How to transform this negative value to positive with jQuery ?

Comment: What's happening here that doesn't let you simply `x *= -1`? I feel like there should be more to this

Comment: Why two different questions for the same item? Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513835/get-positive-css-transforme-value not the same as this one?

Comment: @Harry because my first question was not precise and did not make sense.

Comment: @Xroad: Ok but it would have made more sense to either edit the previous question to make it more clear (or) delete it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Math.abs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
var x = Math.abs(values[5]);
```